# Mat-select with *ngIf causing ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a `mat-form-field` which I want to contain an input or a select.

When I use an < input > the `*ngIf` works fine. However, when I use a `< mat-select >` like below it throws the `'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError'`.

I think this has only started happening since I've updated my angular versions to:

> Angular CLI: 8.2.1
> Node: 10.16.2
> Angular: 9.0.0-next.1

Why should it work with an input and not a select?

Here is the html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input *ngIf="input.name!=='Bid'" matInput [(ngModel)]="input.value">
  <mat-select *ngIf="input.name==='Bid'" [(value)]="input.value">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let s of statuses" name="status" [value]="s">{{s}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-placeholder class="placeholder">{{input.name}}</mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>
```

The input.name properties are set in a method called in the ngOnInit() like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.prepareInputs();
}
```

Comment: Does the `prepareInputs` method load data asynchronously?

Comment: @Scorpioo590 Nope. They are merely calcuations done on inputs from the parent component. Essentially extra fields added to existing objects

Comment: what happens when you moved `this.prepareInputs();` from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: @Stavm I fixed the problem. It was caused by a `<mat-placeholder>` not having the same `*ngIf` applied to it. This caused it to hang around and mess with the `<mat-select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the `<mat-placeholder>` line, which did not have the `*ngIf` applied to it, so when the input was not chosen, the `<mat-placeholder>` was causing things to jam up! When I put the `*ngIf` on the `<mat-placeholder>` the problem disappeared.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input *ngIf="input.name!=='Bid'" matInput [(ngModel)]="input.value">
  <mat-placeholder *ngIf="input.name!=='Bid'" class="placeholder">{{input.name}}</mat-placeholder>
  <mat-select *ngIf="input.name==='Bid'" [(value)]="input.value">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let s of statuses" name="status" [value]="s">{{s}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```